# AngularJS com Socket.io e dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

A seguinte *query* em `cidade.php` busca quantos pedidos estão abertos em determinada cidade, que bloqueia um link. Caso seja `0`, a soma da *query* libera o link. Caso seja maior que `1` bloqueia o link.

Controlador AngularJS

```
app.controller('CityCtrl', function($rootScope, $http)
{
    $http.get('app/querys/cidade.php').success(function(data) {
      $rootScope.citys = data;
    });
```

Index.html

```
 <div ng-controller="CityCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="city in citys">{{city.name}} : {{city.amount}}</div>
 </div>
```

Mas é nessa parte que está o problema, como  fazer pra sempre estar conferindo quantos pedidos tem em aberto?

- por WebSocket
- ou Soket.io.js
- ou setInterval

Qual dessas aplicações seria mais leve?

Comment: Quão regular é "sempre"? Uma vez por minuto? Por segundo? Imediatamente? Para cada uma dessas respostas há uma solução mais eficiente.

Comment: entao depende o cliente vai mandar os dados pra o mysql... dai pra frente atualiza tanto faz se for por segundo ou imediatamente... mais tem que ser o mais leve possivel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ainda esta um pouco inconclusiva sua pergunta, mas acredito já ser possível abordar de modo que você possa tirar suas próprias conclusões.

Em primeiro lugar, Socket.IO é um módulo do NodeJS. Logo, se sua aplicação esta em PHP, utilizá-lo não deve ser uma opção já que seria necessário ter um servidor NodeJS só para este serviço. Não conheço Socket.IO mais a fundo, mas acredito que ele utilize WebSocket para fazer a comunicação com o cliente.

WebSocket mantém uma conexão ativa com o servidor, e portanto consumindo recursos constantemente. Assim, se sua necessidade é de que as alterações no servidor sejam propagadas para o cliente quase que instantaneamente, sem dúvida esta é sua única opção.

Por `setInterval`, estou assumindo que será efetuada uma requisição AJAX no intervalo estipulado. Deve-se então considerar o tempo necessário para estabelecer a conexão TCP, que é de pelo menos 3x a latência entre o cliente e o servidor (o TCP utiliza Three-Way-Handshake), e nisto eu não estou se quer considerando o uso de HTTPS, o que aumentaria muito mais tempo até que a **requisição** comece a ser trafegada devido à negociação do protocolo SSL/TLS.

Na minha opinião, se você deseja que as atualizações ocorram em menos de 2 segundos, eu estudaria seriamente o WebSocket. Do contrário (que é a grande maioria dos casos), `setInterval` será o mais indicado.

**Exemplo com WebSocket**

Para facilitar o uso do WebSocket em PHP, recomendo usar a biblioteca [PHP WebSockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets). O esqueleto de uma aplicação usando esta biblioteca é o seguinte:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once('./WebSockets.php');

class echoServer extends WebSocketServer {

  protected function process ($user, $message) {
    // processas as mensagens do cliente. No caso, é um eco apenas.
    $this->send($user, $message);
  }

  protected function connected ($user) {
    // inicialização executada quando um cliente é conectado.
  }

  protected function closed ($user) {
    // limpeza executada quando o cliente é desconectado.
  }
}

// cria o servidor na porta 9000 em todas as interfaces.
$echo = new echoServer("0.0.0.0", "9000");

try {
  $echo->run();
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
  $echo->stdout($e->getMessage());
}
```

Este exemplo foi retirado do site [PHP Builder](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html).

O cliente não possui nada de especial: ele é o mesmo seja NodeJS ou PHP.

Você deve adaptar este exemplo para funcionar no seu provedor de hospedagem.

**Sobre lentidão**

Não sei se entendi direito o que você disse nos comentários, mas se você tem uma requisição levando 10 segundos que com `setInterval` leva 30s, tem alguma coisa muito errada aí. O tempo de processamento de uma requisição deve ficar sempre na casa dos mili-segundos, que é inclusive a ordem dos tempos para a realização do handshake. Assim, se você tem uma latência de 50ms para o servidor, e 100ms necessários para processar a requisição, eu esperaria um tempo mínimo de 250ms para a finalização da requisição (este é muito próximo do melhor caso, inclusive).

Porém, 10 segundos para o processamento de uma requisição é uma eternidade, e a simples troca para `setInterval` não justifica um aumento de 30s a não ser que o servidor esteja sofrendo com ataques de DDoS. Considere otimizar suas queries, analisar algorítmos ou até a troca para uma hospedagem melhor (ou até uma VPS ou Cloud).

Comment: Vinicio como uso o WebSocket todos que axei me parecia usar node.js tenho um servidor na uolhost sera que tem como implementar isso la? ou estou procurando o conteudo errado?

Comment: cara to com setinterval ou verdade mesmo e 3x a requisição no script ta 10 seg no cliente foi 30seg... como mecho com websocket pode me mostrar algo?

Comment: Maior parte do pessoal implementa WebSocket com NodeJS mesmo, mas é possível sim implementar em outras linguagens, inclusive PHP. Vou atualizar a resposta com um exemplo bem curto.

Comment: Top Vinicios :D ja consegui ate rodar hehe

Comment: Legal! Parabéns!

Comment: parabens nada muito obrigado :D